# Relation between drawFocus, paint() and paintBackground() method in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to know what is the relation between drawFocus(), paint() and paintBackground() method in BlackBerry development. When any specific method is called and what is the order of execution. I tried to understand myself but could not get glean much from it.

Comment: Here is another [example from the BlackBerry docs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Implement_the_painting_methods_1676240_11.jsp) that might shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

The best why to find out which order methods are executed in, and what causes them to be executed, is to create a custom object (e.g. a field derived from the field you are interested in) and override those methods in your custom object.

Then set breakpoints on those methods, and debug.

Comment: Hi paulkayuk : Thanx for the reply, but i want to know the exact purpose of these functions not just the order of execution. I could not understand much from the documentation given.

Comment: My understanding is that you would override the paintbackground method for a field if you want to apply any custom graphics to the background elements of the field e.g. to apply a custom background or border. You would override the paint method for a field if you want to apply any custom graphics to the foreground elements of the field e.g. the text of an edit field. You would override the drawfocus method if you want to apply any custom graphics when the field has or hasn't got focus. e.g. change the colour of the field and or text for each of those two states.